# How to set a monopaced font in code-blocks?

Tags: emacs, fonts, markdown, font-face

My standard font is a proportional one. When I edit markdown files I would like to have all sections that are indented by 4 or more spaces be shown in a monospaced font.

I do not use any special markdown mode. Therefore I would be ok if I had to to switch that behavior manually on for the current buffer. Although, my own mode for `*.md`-files would be need of course, but I have no idea how to do that (and is beyond the scope if this question).

The modes that are active for me are:

```
Enabled minor modes: Abbrev Auto-Composition
    Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption Blink-Cursor 
    Column-Highlight Column-Number Desktop-Save File-Name-Shadow
    Flyspell Font-Lock Global-Font-Lock Icomplete Line-Number
    Menu-Bar Mouse-Wheel Shell-Dirtrack Show-Paren
    Tooltip Transient-Mark
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you do need a mode that highlights markdown code. (Try `M-x package-install RET markdown-mode+ RET`) If you have font-locking enabled (I suspect you have), the mode that you end up probably gives syntax highlighting for markdown.

Now, syntax highlighting is just alterations to font and color used. Once you have it on, you can customize the font face used for code by navigating over a code block and issuing `M-x customize-face`. My markdown mode has code blocks under `markdown-pre-face`; the face under cursor will be selected by default for you.

I prepared some screenshots to show the workflow. Determining what emacs allows for font family or foundry is bit of a dark magic, and I leave it to google to find out more about it. On linux systems there used to be an ugly little helper called `xfontsel` where you can preview different font families and foundries.

You can experiment without saving anything first by applying the changes without saving; when things look fine, you can "apply and save" in the customize mode.

[image: screenshots of how to adjust font-face in Emacs]

Comment: `markdown-mode+` shows "(No matches)". `markdown-mode` would match, though. Will that mode be "enough"? I think I installed it already some time ago (and didnt like it much).

Comment: @towi: The only thing that we need from the mode is that font locking. The one you already have should be plenty. Sorry if you don't like it, but some sort of mode has to be on in order to special font locking to happen. A mode is just code that can be pruned to give only the syntax portions but it's a bit advanced. If you have anything about the mode in particular that you want to disable, make a new question about it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to partially disagree with the argument that you can do what you are after. You can only partially do what you are after and it is a bit of a hack.

Basically, you can set different fonts for different faces. So, provided the text you want to display in a fixed width font has a different face definition, then you can change the font from a proportional font to a fixed width font. At least, that is the theory.

Unfortunately, the results tend to be less than you would hope.

The problem is that most modes do not define faces for all possible characters. Faces tend to only be used to make something stand out and that tends to mean something which is special in the mode - a heading, a bit of syntax etc.

The problem will be witht he 'default face - the face used when no other face is specified. The default face is not mode specific. If you set default face to a monospace font, that font will be used in all modes, not just in 'plain' characters within markdown mode. If any of your fonts in markdown mode are proportional, you will find that alignment in indentation will not look consistent. Depending on how you structure your buffer contents, this may or may not be an issue.

Personally, I gave up on using a proportioanl font as the default font under emacs a long time ago and have settled instead on using a fixed width font as the default and then defining proportional fonts for some speial purposes, such as org-mode headers.

some things you could try which *might* work, would be

- File local variables for setting fonts just in markdown filtes. I've not tried this, but you may be able to use file local variables. You would probably want to create a markdown template which sets this up in new markdown filtes.
- Make the face variables buffer local. You might be able to define a markdown-mode hook function which makes the face variables buffer local and sets them to a fixed width font.

Face definitions can use inheritance, so theoretically, if all the faces used inherit from default face and you do a file local variable or buffer local variable to set the default face, then all other faces *should* inherit that definition, so you shouldn't have to do it for every font in the buffer.

Comment: Actually, I got it working and am pleased enough with the result. Right, not 100%, nut close enough (e.g. if I have something in a code block that resembles an URL markdown-mode/fontlock detect them and format them proportially inside the code-block. ugh). I use proportional font in emacs for ... oh I dont know... 7 years... now and am satisfied enough. I don't do emacs magic, only small conjuring tricks, though. `col-highlight-mode` and *multicursors* `mc/...` are a bit bumpy to look at, but my brain adjusted to it.

Comment: If it works and scratches your itch enough, all the better. I like the better look of proportional fonts, but most of my emacs work is with code and shell interaction. Having things like dired buffers or shell output losing alignment or code looking odd is enough to make me stick with mainly fixed width. Luckily, there are some better looking fixed width fonts these days.